# Does Karate support API mocking for gRPC?

Tags: mocking, grpc, karate

In the documentation for [Karate Netty](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-netty), we learn how to make API test-doubles to mock other services which our tests may have to call. This is a very useful feature.

I now would like to make an API test-double for a service which accepts only gRPC requests. I'm not sure how to go about this since the existing examples (like the [cats](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/mock/web) example) seem to be based on REST. But in gRPC paths are static and, for example, there are no path params.

Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at the moment, and it does sound like a good feature request for the future.

I think your best bet is to write a small one-time gRPC server for your specific needs. Karate uses [Armeria](https://armeria.dev/) behind the scenes, so adding gRPC support should be relatively easy. Open-source contributions in the form of pull-requests are of course welcome.